# Raw SQL with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to write a simple raw query with Entity Framework to my database:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Customer))]
[Route("name/{name}")]
[HttpGet]
public List<Customer> GetCustomerName(string name)
{
    //var results = db.Customers.SqlQuery("SELECT Name from dbo.Customer").Where(p => p.Name.Equals(name)).ToList();
    var results = db.Customers.SqlQuery("SELECT Name from dbo.Customer WHERE Name = @Name",new SqlParameter("@Name",name)).ToList();
    //var results = db.Customers.Where(p => p.Name.Equals(name));
    return results;
}
```

The last Entity Framework query works just fine, but I want to do raw SQL to get something back simple because I have never gotten raw SQL with Entity Framework to work and I see all of these examples where people says it works for them. The top 2 var results do not work I get this error any help would be greatly appreciated. I am a Web API 2 newbie and I am just trying to learn it

[image]

So the error says a member of the type `AccrRevAcct` does not have a corresponding column. I am not sure what that means `AccrRevAcct` is a column on my database but so is Name and I just want the Name of my customer.

```
http://localhost:61280/api/Customers/name/1st MIDAMERICA CREDIT UNION
```

This is the call I make to my server and like I said it returns fine with the 3rd statement but that isn't raw SQL like I want to achieve. I only want to do this because I have some developers saying they can't get everything to work in EF I personally like it and haven't ran into this problem I want to show them fine just drop to raw SQL, but I need to show them I can make it work first lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `SqlQuery` on the `DbSet` you have to return a full instance. If you want to reshape the data like you are doing you need to use the `SqlQuery<T>` on the `db.Database` instead.

Example from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blogNames = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>( 
                       "SELECT Name FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList(); 
}
```

Comment: hey thank you for your response I actually tried this and I get an error the non generic method dbSet<customer>.SqlQuery(string.params object[]) cannot be used with type arguments.

Comment: I got the same thing on trying this with the ef where statement so I got this error with both  var results = db.Customers.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT Name from dbo.Customer").Where(p => p.Name.Equals(name)).ToList(); and with var results = db.Customers.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT Name from dbo.Customer WHERE Name = @Name",new SqlParameter("@Name",name)).ToList();

Comment: or <Customer> still does the same thing

Comment: You haven't followed the example correctly. `db.Database.SqlQuery<string>()` not `db.Customers.SqlQuery<string>()`.

Comment: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException occurred
  HResult=0x8013193C
  Message=The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'SIVAOSModel.Customer'. A member of the type, 'AccrRevAcct', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>  same error this is my code 
            var results = db.Database.SqlQuery<Customer>("SELECT Name from dbo.Customer WHERE Name = @Name", new SqlParameter("@Name", name)).ToList();

Comment: I love you dude I figured it out I had to make a new class instead of following my old class I scaffold  out called it myResults    public class myResults
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }   then I just did it the same way but passed in this class wouldn't got there without you though  var results = db.Database.SqlQuery<myResults>("SELECT Name from dbo.Customer WHERE Name = @Name", new SqlParameter("@Name", name)).ToList();

            return results;

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I think you are trying to solve the wrong problem. The last query is the one you should be using. If your developers can't get EF to work that is what needs to be fixed.